# Pass a PHP variable (loop-audio.php) to jQuery function (js/script.js)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, javascript, json

I've searched a lot for this and I seem to get different answers.

In my situation, my jQuery function has to use a PHP variable from a different file.

How can I accomplish this? Clear and simple answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it your own file or a WordPress core file? And are you loading the script with wp_enqueue_script?

Comment: None of the files I mentioned are core files. All are created by me.
EDIT: Yes, I can run scripts in the JS file.

Comment: This is off topic and should be moved to StackOverflow.

Comment: It depends. If it is about how to do it in WordPress it should stay.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this function lets you localize your JS strings, but you can also use it to set global JS variables:

```
function set_my_js_var() {
    // logic here for returning the right JS var
    $myVar = "Hello World";
    return $myVar;
}
function load_fe_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'global-js-var', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my_file.js' );
    $localize_array = array(
        'my_js_var' => set_my_js_var()
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'global-js-var', 'my_global', $localize_array );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_fe_scripts');
```

You can now acces the var in your JS File by `my_global.my_js_var`

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax to get the value from a function read about it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

you can also save the variable in the database with transients if the function runs on every load. http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API

then use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script to load the var to a global javascript var.

Update:
This is a ugly way to do this.
In your template where you want to save the var:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <?php print_var(); ?>
</script>
```

And in your function:

```
<?php
// register a global outside the function
global $myVar;
function MyFunc(){
global $myVar;
...
//save the var in the global!
$MyVar = $a;
...
}

//function
function print_var(){
global $MyVar;
 echo "var myGlobalJsVar = ". $MyVar .";";
}

?>
```

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler answer. I have variable $a = 1. All I want to do is pass $a to my script.js.

Comment: When does the function run in the lifecycle? is it before or after wp_enqueue_script? if it is you can use wp_localize_script. Or you can use a ugly hack. i will update my answer with it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = <?php echo $a=1; ?>
// OR 
var a = <?php global $a; echo $a; ?>
</script>
```

We can directly use PHP variable in javascript as i showed in example

If your php code and javascript code in same page then you can use first approach.
Else your php code in different page and included it in current page then use second approach.

In second approach i used global keyword.

Please go through this link [PHP Language Variables Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)